# setnewhandler in C#

Tags: c#

for creating my own memory management in C# I need to have a possibility to intercept the new command before it returns a null or fires an exception. When using the new command I want to call the original handler first. If this handler fails to return a block of memory, I want to inform all my mappable objects to be written to disk and to free memory.

In C++ there has been a possibility to intercept the new command by assigned a different new handler. In C# I couldn't find anything which shows the same behaviour.

Has anyone seen a possibility to do this.

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you're after in C#, or in any managed language. Nor should you try. The .NET runtime manages allocations and garbage collection. It's impossible for you to instruct your objects to free memory, as you have no guarantee when (or, technically, even *if*) a particular object will be collected once it's no longer rooted. Even eliminating all references and manually calling `GC.Invoke()` is not an absolute guarantee. If you're looking for granular memory management, you need to be using a lower-level environment.

As an important point, it is *not* possible for the `new` operator to return a null reference. It can only return either a reference to the specified type or throw an exception.

If you want to do your own management of how and when objects are allocated, you'll have to use something along the lines of a factory pattern.

Comment: Hi Adam. Thank you for your quick answer. This is what I suspected that I have to create some factory for this. The only problem is that it is an image and math processing library where the developers are not really aware of how to use such patterns. I will have think more over it to find a good solution. Thank you nevertheless...

Comment: @Adam, it is possible for new to return a null reference in the particularly pathological proxy case (credit to Marc Gravell for pointing it out.)  It will also return an object that equates to null (and boxes to null) if the type is `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: @user688164: In most scenarios, factory patterns are implemented in such a way as to preclude the possibility of going around them (in other words, your types are not able to be instantiated with `new` outside of your factory assembly).

Comment: @Dan: True, though that draws us to the distinction between null value (meaning the result of `=null` or comparing with `==null`) and a true null reference. While that point is tangential to the real issue here, it's certainly worth mentioning. Note, though, that I do mention that `new` cannot return a null *reference* (indeed; `new Nullable<T>()` doesn't return a reference at all), not a null *value*.

Comment: @Adam, in the pathological proxy case, it actually can return a true null reference.  That's because 'new' in this case is being auto-magically redirected to a method call, rather than emitting the normal newobj OpCode and constructor call.  If you return null from the proxy generator method, then the returned object from the 'new' call really will be a null reference.

Comment: @Dan: You're right, of course; my comment was referring to the issue with `Nullable<T>`, not proxies.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're approaching this from the wrong angle; the whole point of using a runtime with managed memory is so that you don't have to worry about memory.  The tradeoff is that you can't do this type of low-level trickery.

As an aside, you can 'override new' for a limited class of objects (those descending from [ContextBoundObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.contextboundobject.aspx)) by creating a custom [ProxyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.proxyattribute.aspx), though this likely does not address what you're intending.

Comment: Hi Dan. You are right, this was also my initial guess when I started a few years ago with C# and .NET. The only problem is that we have data that can exceed more than 100GB during processing the data and there it really going to be an issue. Also I have "invented" a possible solution with my own file mapping for myself it does not work in general because there is option to find out when memory gets on the limits. Or do you know a possbility?

Comment: You may want to look into MemoryFailPoint, which is a class designed to help with making your application robust in the face of memory allocation failures.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint.aspx

Comment: I have implemented teh fail point. But this option slows down the system tremendously. I was thinking of a more general way. Otherwise I have to check for the fail point in each command I allcocate a larger amount of memory.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are not understanding the side-effects of what you're asking for.  Even in C++, you can't really do what you think you can do.  The reason is simple, if you have run out of memory, you can't even make your objects serialize to disk because you have no memory to accomplish that.  By the time memory is exhausted, the only real thing you can do is either discard memory (without saving or doing anything else first) or abend the program.

Now, what you're talking about will still work 95% of the time because your memory allocation will likely be sufficiently large that when it fails, you have a little room to play with, but you can't guarantee that this will be the case.

Example:  If you have only 2MB of memory left, and you try to allocate 10MB, then it will fail, and you still have 2MB to play with to try and free up some memory, which will allow you to allocate small chunks of memory needed to serialize objects to disk.

But, if you only have 10 bytes of memory left, then you don't even have enough memory to create a new exception object (unless it comes from a reserved pool).  So, in essence, you're creating a very poor situation that will likely crash at some point.

Even in C++ low memory conditions are almost impossible to get right, and it's almost impossible to recover from every case unless you have very carefully planned, and pre-allocated memory for your recovery routines.

Now, when you're talking about a garbage collected OS, you have no control over how memory is allocated or freed.  At best, all you can do is give hints.  There is very little you can reliably do here by the nature of garbage collection.  It's non-deterministic.

Comment: Hi Mystere Man. Surely I know that there are risk what I'm asking for. In fact I don't like to do the things I have asked for, but I see no other reason. What I would like is to get informed first, when memory is getting low on a threshold I can define. There should be some message in the GC that the system is getting low on memory resources. If I get this message the GC should be able to block all new commands, until I release it. Of course there are several impacts but how would you handle files and data larger than 100GB?

Comment: @user688164 - First, i suggest getting a handle.  The generic name you're using sucks ;) - Second, I don't believe you can allocation 100GB in a single allocation anways, so I think your point is moot.  I think the largest single allocation you can make is 2GB even on a 64 bit OS.  You can allocate multiple 2GB blocks, but any single allocation is limited to 2GB.

Comment: Yes you are right. You can only allocate 2GB. Have you tested the GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification method? First I thought this might be useful but it's running in a different thread and doesn't help get rid of the allocated objects because the allocation can outperform the deallocation which also results in an outofmemoryexception.